# How can I binding DependencyProperty in Style(UWP)?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I wanna make a custom usercontrol which actually just a image button.
Here is my project:
[image]

Here is code of ImageButton.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1.UC
{
    class ImageButton:Button
    {


        public ImageSource BackgroundImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(BackgroundImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundImageProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), null);


    }
}
```

Here is code of ImageButton.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1.UC">
    <Style TargetType="local:ImageButton">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="{Binding local:BackgroundImage}"></Border>
                            <Border Background="Blue"></Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is code of MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page xmlns:my="using:App1.UC" 
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/UC/ImageButton.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <my:ImageButton Height="100" Width="100" BackgroundImage="Assets/Wide310x150Logo.png" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The problem is I can't see the BackgroundImage which I set in my:ImageButton.
I doubted if is something wrong with binding the BackgroundImage in ImageButton.xaml.
I googled about it and found something like [How to bind to attached property in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701255/how-to-bind-to-attached-property-in-uwp)
I tried as it said:

```
{Binding Path=(local:ImageButton.BackgroundImage), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

But no use again.
What's wrong with my programme?Would you please help me ?

Comment: `class ImageButton : Button` declares a derived Button class, not a UserControl. That class won't magically load a ResourceDictionary in a file that accidentially has the same name as the class. Either create a proper UserControl in your Visual Studio project, or take a look at [custom controls with default Styes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_DefaultStyleKey).

Comment: Why are you trying to create your own derived version of a button? as rightly said by @Clemens it just won't work this ways. Why don't you edit the style of the Button Control is all you want to do is change the way the button looks.

Comment: @Clemens Beaucase I wanna to inherit the property of Button,such as foreground fontsize and etc.Is there a better way to inherit Button?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I am not only want to change the style but also want to add a custom property names BackgroundImage.But what is the best way to do ti?

Comment: What does the your backgroundImage property do?

Comment: "Is there a better way to inherit Button?" There is only *one* way to inherit from Button. That's how you did it. However, if you want to declare a default Style for the derived Button, it has to be in a ResourceDictionary called `Generic.xaml` in a `Themes` folder in your Visual Studio project. You also need to set the derived Button's `DefaultStyleKey` property. Read the online documentation.

Comment: @AdityaSharma Well,the button has a background color and a background image,I want to use background property to binding the background color,and the custom property BackgroundImage to binding the background image.

Comment: So you want the background image and a background colour at the same time? Am I getting it right?

Comment: @AdityaSharma yeah,that's why I used border twice in the xaml,one border to show the background image and one border to show the background color.

Comment: Do you want to have a button with background colour and a background picture is that what you want? Both dynamically set at runtime

Comment: @AdityaSharma yes,that's what I need as you said.I just found a tutorial maybe helpful:http://www.wyzard.us/creating-a-custom-native-control-in-uwp-3/ .However I followed the tutorial,but the programme crash at the binding in BackgroundImage again.

Comment: @AdityaSharma I tried Justin XL's answer,it works now~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to extend the `Button` just for displaying an image as its background. You can use `ImageBrush` directly like this

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Wide310x150Logo.png" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

---

### Update

Extending an existing control with additional dependency properties can be simplified to the following steps.

**1.** Right click on your project, then go *Add* > *New Item...*. In the popup, select *Templated Control* and give it a
    name `ImageButton.cs`.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Visual Studio will now automatically generate a new folder called
`Themes` with a `ResourceDictionary` file named `Generic.xaml`,
which is where the default style of your `ImageButton` goes.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Visual Studio will also generate an `ImageButton` class with the
following code.

    public sealed class ImageButton : Control
    {
        public ImageButton()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ImageButton);
        }
    }
```

**2.** Change the base class to `Button` and add your own dependency property to the class.

```
    public sealed class ImageButton : Button

    public ImageSource BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(BackgroundImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), null);
```

**3.** Provide your own style and put it inside `Generic.xaml`. Note you
    will need to use `TemplateBinding` to pass values from your
    dependency properties to the binding targets.

```
        <Style TargetType="local:ImageButton">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ImageButton">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{TemplateBinding BackgroundImage}"></Border>
                                ...
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
```

That's it. Now, you can use it like below

```
<my:ImageButton Height="100" Width="100" BackgroundImage="Assets/Wide310x150Logo.png" />
```

Comment: It is the easiest way which I used to do it.However,there is so many place need to use the ImageButton.It is so troublesome that always type the code or copy/paste the code.So I want to make a usercontrol to make it more convenient to use.

Comment: UserControl? But from the code in your question, you are creating a custom control. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am sorry about my mistake.It is custom control but not usercontrol.

Comment: Yes,it works.But I found another problem and solved it.The problem is I used Border to show the background image,but the it won't show the image.I should use Image to show it instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Yeah you will need to use `ImageBrush` if you want to use a `Border`. But I'd go with `Image` as it does automatic decoding.